# Adding a filter to a table - ruby on rails (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datatables

Here I'm trying to add a filter for the "organisation" column. This uses datatables library to handle the tables The `profiles.js` file pass neccessary inputs to the `_status_table.erb` file .

in `profiles.js` file I added these extra lines ,

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
 //existing code 
  if (!document.querySelector(".profiles.index, .users.admin_edit")) return;

  initDataTable({ tableId: "#profilesTable", orderVal: 1, targetsVal: [0, 4] });
  processCoderIdUpdate();

  $(".menu .item").tab();

  
  initDataTable({
    tableId: "#profilesStatusTable",
    orderVal: 1,
    sortingDirection: "asc",
    targetsVal: [0, 7]
  });

  // I added this below custom event listner for get the value from other file 


    $("#organizationFilterDropdown").dropdown();

  // Attach the change event listener
  $("#organizationFilterDropdown").on("change", function() {
    var selectedOrganizationId = $(this).dropdown("get value");

    // Get the table instance
    var profilesStatusTable = $("#profilesStatusTable").DataTable();

    // Clear any existing filters
    profilesStatusTable.columns().search("").draw();

    // Apply the filter to the "Organisation" column
    profilesStatusTable
      .columns(5)
      .search(selectedOrganizationId, false, false)
      .draw();
  });
```

and in the `_status_table.html.erb` I added this dropdown section

```
<div class="ui fluid labeled search selection dropdown" id="organizationFilterDropdown" data-selected-organization="<%= @selected_organization %>">
  <input type="hidden" id="organizationFilterInput">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text">Filter by Organization</div>
  <div class="menu">
    <% @organizations.each do |organization| %>
      <div class="item" data-value="<%= organization.id %>"><%= organization.name_or_code %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the rest of the `_status_table.html.erb`

```
<table id="profilesStatusTable" class="ui celled table">  
  <%= render partial: 'profiles/table_actions' %>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class="ui checkbox">
          <%= check_box_tag 'select_all', 1, false, class: "select-all", onclick: "toggleAll(this)" %>
          <label></label>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>Full Name</th>
      <th>Role</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Confirmed</th>
      <th>Organisation</th>
      <th>Coder ID</th>
      <th>Created at</th>
      <th>Last Updated</th>
      <th>Last Login at</th>
      <th>Login Count</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @profiles.each do |profile| %>
      <tr class="<%= cycle('row', 'alt-row') %>">
        <td><%= check_box_tag 'delete[]', profile.user.id %><label></label></td>
        <td><%= profile.user.full_name %></td>
        <td><%= role_as_string(profile.role_key) %></td>
        <td><%= profile.user.email %></td>
        <td>
          <span class="ui <%= profile.user.confirmed ? 'teal' : 'red'%> empty circular label"></span>
        </td>
        <td><%= profile.organisation.name_or_code %></td>
        <td><%= profile.coder_id.present? ? profile.coder_id : 'N/A' %></td>
        <td><%= localise_and_pretty_print(profile.user.created_at) %></td>
        <td><%= localise_and_pretty_print(profile.user.updated_at) %></td>
        <td><%= localise_and_pretty_print(profile.user.last_login_at) %></td>
        <td><%= profile.user.login_count %></td>
        <td>
          <%= link_to admin_edit_user_path(profile.user), class: "icon-action", title: "Edit" do %>
            <i class="edit icon"></i>
          <% end %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The issue is when I select a value from dropdown it shows empty table, I did enter `console.log("selectedOrganizationId");` inside `onchange() function` and it prints the correct value.

I was referring to [this](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) section and implemented above code, please help me if you can

Comment: You failed to add the necessary jQuery to instantiate the dropdown `$('#organizationFilterDropdown').dropdown();`

Comment: @engineersmnky 
  I added that line, still when I select a value from dropdown it shows empty table I'll update the question based on my latest findings, thanks

Comment: You might want to include a small example of your table. Additionally `profilesStatusTable` does not appear to have a reference. Are there errors in the console?

Comment: @engineersmnky I'll add the table then, no there're no errors in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`profilesStatusTable` has no reference so if you were actually getting to this action it would raise `TypeError: profilesStatusTable.column is not a function`.

Since you are saying there are no errors it is possible that this guard clause `if (!document.querySelector(".profiles.index, .users.admin_edit")) return;` is hiding them from you, as I cannot reproduce your issue. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/b68yk7jm/).

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
 profilesStatusTable = new DataTable("#profilesStatusTable",{
    tableId: "#profilesStatusTable",
    orderVal: 1,
    sortingDirection: "asc",
    targetsVal: [0, 7]
  });
 $("#organizationFilterDropdown").dropdown(
    {onChange: function() {
        var selectedOrganizationId = $(this).dropdown("get value");
        // Apply the filter to the "Organisation" column
        profilesStatusTable.column(5).search(selectedOrganizationId).draw();
    }})
});
```

Note:

- Since `initDataTable` is also not a function defined anywhere I used the standard syntax for `DataTables`.
- I chose to pass the `onChange` function to `dropdown` because it IMO it looks cleaner and contains the associated logic better; however, your implementation would work exactly the same.

**UPDATE**
Along with the above issues I later noted that the OP is trying to use `orginazation.id` as a search parameter but is searching against the `profile.organisation.name_or_code` so the extended solution was also to change

```
<div class="item" data-value="<%= organization.id %>">
```

to

```
<div class="item" data-value="<%= organization.name_or_code %>">
```

Comment: since it had no reference I slightly modified the on change function. Feel free to take a look.

Comment: issues meann I did add your modifications to the above modified code of mine as it should work. But after filter , it returns empty table without records. I even uncommented the guard clause, still no errors in the console.

Comment: my god! haha That was it!!!! Thank you very much Mr ! I'm such a mess rn haha